# Get specific attribute value from select box using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have one drop down i want to get value of price, and it has be plus with already one price available at up.

```
<p class="price">USD 200<p>

<select name="options[7]" id="select_7" class=" required-entry product-custom-option">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="13" price="15">Medium 14.5cm +USD15.00</option>
<option value="14" price="35">Large - 16.5cm +USD35.00</option>
</select>
```

I want whenever any value from drop down changed than price attr needs to be add to the base price at `<P>` tag.

Also if someone deselect value than it has be minus from base price at `<p>` tag.

How can i achieve that ?

Any help would be appreciate.
 Thanks In advance.

Comment: What you done yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use J query change event to detect drop-down change value. then using drop-down:selected attribute you can get data value of drop-down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select_7').on("change", function() {
        if ($("#select_7 option:selected").attr('value') == "") {
            $('.price').text("USD");
            $('.price2').text("USD " + parseInt(200));
        } else {
            var dataid = $("#select_7 option:selected").attr('price');
            
            $('.price').text("USD " + dataid);
            var dataPrice = 200 + parseInt(dataid);
            $('.price2').text("USD " + dataPrice);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="price">USD 200<p>
<p class="price2">USD 200<p>
   <select name="options[7]" id="select_7" class="required-entry product-custom-option">
      <option value="">Select Size</option>
      <option value="13" price="15">Medium 14.5cm +USD15.00</option>
      <option value="14" price="35">Large - 16.5cm +USD35.00</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

One another approach is to maintain the lookup array like

```
          var lookup = [];
          lookup["13"] = {price : 100 , OtherStuff : ''};
```

now you can get the selected value

```
     var selected = $("#Id").val()
     var moreDetail = lookup[selected];
```

This will keep you html cleaner and you can add more stuff to your lookup object.

Answer (score 0):

`price` is not a html attribute. use `data-price`.

how to select:-

html:-

```
<option vaue="13" data-price="15"></option>
```

jquery:-

```
var price = $('option[value="13"]').data('price');
//price = 15
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.required-entry').bind('change',function(){
  $('.price').html('USD '+$('.required-entry option[value="'+$('.required-entry').val()+'"]').data('price'));
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="price"><p>

<select name="options[7]" id="select_7" class="required-entry product-custom-option">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="13" data-price="15">Medium 14.5cm +USD15.00</option>
<option value="14" data-price="35">Large - 16.5cm +USD35.00</option>
</select>
```